# css and animation problem on mouseenter

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, css

My code is quite long but I have commented on my jQuery script. My problem is when you mouse over the menu items it animates but it pushes to much  ever so slightly three or so pixels to the right. I've been playing around with it for ages and i can't get it quite perfect, it will take a little bit of time to go through it but if you can solve my problem it would be much appreciated. here the the link on jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/g6tAn/

Comment: Could you add a screenshot showing the issue you're talking about? Also, the HTML is [tag-soup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_soup)-tastic.

Comment: what browser do you use? Seems OK in chrome.

Comment: minimize the results frame on jsFiddle then you will my problem

Comment: Whoa! That is giving me a headache :-)

Comment: check your CSS - if you have two classes for each state, make sure things like borders are identical widths.

Comment: I've gone over heaps of time if you or someone can figure it out would be awsome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is happening because of the `<table>` layout. The browser can and will squeeze `<td>` elements when it does not have enough page width to render the table at its *natural width*. You can see that the *small* bouncing effect you are seeing is vastly amplified in a very narrow browser window.

I [**made a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/uKRhL/1/) with a completely different layout. It works in Chrome12 but I was not really aware of the problems other browsers have with `list-style-image` so it's a bit broken in other browsers. You could just remove that CSS for a better cross-browser demo.

Or you could just add `style="width:600px"` to your `<table>` which fixes the problem (unless you need a dynamic width table of course…)

Comment: Thankyou for telling me that and redoing what I did. My other question is when you mouse over a menu item then go to another div element that has a another menu item how do you keep the hover state on the div element before

Comment: It depends on the structure really. If it's a menu &rarr; sub-menu you would usually mark-up the sub-menu inside the menu, therefore a `hover()` or `mouseover()` event would still be applicable when hovering on a menu item or its sub-menu. If the sub-menu has a different parent element to the menu then you could use `mouseenter()` on the menu to show the sub-menu and `mouseleave()` on the sub-menu to close it. If you need more information I might need to know a little about the menu structure in order to help.